How to fetch more than 1000 activities from a GetStream feed?
Based on the getStream.io documentation, there is a limit of fetching a maximum of 1000 recent activities from a feed. What if we need access to older feeds?
Let's consider a scenario: there are 10000 users actively posting activities, and user X has a feed following those 10000 users' feeds. When fetching feeds for user X, it will show the posts from the followed 10000 users, but it will miss the majority of posts because they won't fit within the 1000-activity limit. What’s the solution for this?

Are you trying to get all posts from those 10000 feeds at once? Or you are thinking of when the user scrolled down to the end of 1000 posts?

Yes, when the user scrolls down to the end of 1000 posts. I know that it is not normal to scroll so much, but this was a requirement to have the ability to do so.

GetStream offers an alternative approach for fetching activities using Batch Methods. The activityId or a combination of foreignId + time can be used to fetch all activities that were created. Implementers should store minimal details such as userId, activityId, or foreignId + time in their database for each activity, so they can retrieve them through GetStream.
https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/docs/java/add_many_activities/?language=java#batch-get-activities-by-id
